# An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4557EC3B)

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, developer-console

3 hours trying to open google play console but after loading several minutes this error always pop up

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (4557EC3B)

I've signed out from all google account and resigned again and still the same issue,

am I the only one facing this issue?

Comment: after waiting 2 hours, everything back as expected, the problem was on google side

Comment: Same problem here, August 2021.  Persisted for 3 days so far.